# upload App Icon for iPad Pro in xcode 7.1

Tags: app-store-connect, xcode7.1

I am uploading app to iTunes store. When i am uploading my app using application loader the error appears.

[image: EROR ITMS-90023]

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Do you have the icon within the bundle?

Comment: their is no slot for adding iPad Pro icon in AppIcon in side Assets.xcassets in Xcode 7.1

Comment: share screenshot of your Assets.xcassets

Comment: @Amod please check the question. edited.

Comment: @Ben  - there are no images in uploaded image. That is the problem. You need to add images for all configuration selected

Comment: @Ben You should probably update to the latest version of Xcode (7.3.1)

Comment: added image for all configuration.. in that screen shot i am just create a new Image set to show you.

Comment: Using Latest Version Xcode solve my problem. Thanks Oddie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to the latest version of Xcode (7.3.1) Solve it.